Is the use of typeof like how it's done in this code considered bad practice?
I have a struct like:
typedef struct {
    int row;
    int col;
    double *entries;
} Matrix;

I want to write functions to create, free, etc. For example:
Matrix *mtalloc(typeof((Matrix) {}.row) row, typeof((Matrix) {}.col) col)
{
    Matrix *p = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mtalloc(%x, %x): malloc returned NULL\n", row, col);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    p->row = row;
    p->col = col;
    p->entries = malloc(sizeof(*((Matrix) {}.entries)) * row * col);
    return p;
}

This way the function won't have to be changed if the type of the fields in struct change but is it fine or bad practice?

Matter of opinion. What's more clearly a bad practice in my opinion is the function calling malloc twice when one call would do.

@PetrSkocik No. The additional malloc() makes life easier for the calling code by localizing responsibility for things like resize to the referenced struct instead of propagating it back to the calling code.

The typeof is a cool trick, but the functions are part of the Matrix interface. Just how likely do you think the type of row and col will change? If not “very” then you are just making your code over-complicated when an easy search and replace pass can fix things, should an ABI-breaking kind of change needs to be made. (Remember, using code will need update too.) Best to just decide on hard limits now. In all reality, int should be sufficient to index any dense matrix you can fit in memory.

I'd just typedef the size type in my code base. Easier on the eyes and more easily reusable in other functions and so forth.

@Dúthomhas Eliminating the first malloc introduces little resizing issues. Either you alloc the whole thing in one chunk and have a resize function take a Matrix**, or have the caller alloc it (hopefully on the callstack stack or in some other cheap fashion) and then a resizing function can take Matrix*. Mallocing small fixed sized objects is a waste, IMO, but sure it can work (less efficiently) too.

@PetrSkocik No. It has nothing to do with “efficiency” issues using malloc(). It just makes calling code have to deal with managing a pointer value. The “solution” of adding stars (adding another level of indirection in the user code) just moves the problem from encapsulation in the struct to the calling code, and that is a bad design. But again, use case matters, so, let’s assume OP at least has a better idea about that and focus on the (different) issue being asked...?

This code is of questionable quality because it unnecessarily uses a fancy feature and in a way that requires complicated punctuation (parentheses, braces, and such). There is a better way using long-existing features in C:
typedef int MatrixRowT;
typedef int MatrixColT;

typedef struct {
    MatrixRowT row;
    MatrixColT col;
    double *entries;
} Matrix;


Matrix *mtalloc(MatrixRowT row, MatrixColT col)
…

Like the previous code, changing the type of row or col requires changing the code in only one place. However, it is easier to read.
If row and col are expected never to be different types, this can be further reduced to a single type for them.
This code:
    p->entries = malloc(sizeof(*((Matrix) {}.entries)) * row * col);

does not need a compound literal; it can simply be:
    p->entries = malloc(sizeof *p->entries * row * col);

There should also be documentation of what mtalloc does, constraints on the argument values passed, and how the memory it allocates should be freed. There should also be a test for failure in the second malloc.

Since the OP set no requirements on the struct's size, why not use the size specific type size_t? To me it's always a code smell to type sizes with anything else.
